# Правильно ли я написал сортировку вставками?

Tags: java, сортировка

Изучаю различные методы сортировки. Руки дошли до сортировки вставками, код написал, все работает, но закрались сомнения, что это сортировка вставками, а не что либо другое.

```
private static int[] insertionSorting (int array[]) {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
            if(i+1==array.length) break;
            if(array[i+1]<array[j]) {
                    temp = array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int element : array) System.out.print(element+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То что вы написали это пузырьковая сортировка. 
А сортировка вставками выглядит так:

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {  
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int current = array[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && current < array[j]) {
            array[j+1] = array[j];
            j--;
        }
         // в этой точке мы вышли, так что j так же -1 
         // или в первом элементе, где текущий >= a[j]
        array[j+1] = current;
    }
}
```

А вообще такой простой вопрос можно было [нагуглить](https://google.gik-team.com/?q=java+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8).

Comment: Большое спасибо)